# Why doesn't Stack Exchange have a 'gadget enthusiasts' community?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

It would be awesome to have a community of gadget enthusiasts which discusses the current and upcoming gadgets and their features. It could also provide experienced suggestions on gadgets or maybe a rating also.

Is there any reason why it is not already present?

Comment: Discussion isn't what Stack Exchange is about, though. While it might be great to have such a community, it doesn't belong on SE, which is completely about tightly focused questions that can be answered and not just discussed.

Comment: @Chris Hayes ,Thanks but I can see there is a tag for discussion also.

Comment: That's specifically for meta, for the community to come to a consensus on community issues. There is very deliberately no such tag for the main sites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had one. It was one of the earliest SE 2.0 sites, and it floundered rather painfully. The problem was that the topic was just too broad.

You had people coming to ask questions about cordless phones but not interested in answering questions about smart thermostats, or the other huge variety of things 'gadget' describes. More simply, the topic was so broad that there weren't any real experts that could answer more than a handful of questions.

When it came to phones and players, other sites specifically catered to them so .. gadgets just became a catch-all where you were lucky to get an answer.

With the Internet of Things increasingly growing, it *could* be time to think about a support-like site for thermostats, refrigerators, lighting systems, sound systems and the like which can be addressed programmatically via net connectivity, but it'd still be a bit of a longshot and difficult to scope successfully.

Comment: That does sound like Home Automation which was closed down in beta... Again, too broad and maybe too early?

Answer (score 2):

The [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) site never made it out of beta, due to low activity.